numpy tuple-style argsort ordered pairs of ordered pairs?
I have an array of ordered pairs of ordered pairs:
foo = np.array([
   [[1, 3],
    [2, 4]],

   [[4, 1],
    [2, 3]],

   [[3, 2],
    [3, 1]],

   [[2, 4],
    [3, 1]],

   [[1, 2],
    [3, 4]]])

I would like to argsort each pair of pairs, in the usual python tuple sorting sense:
full_argsort(foo) == np.array(
      [[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]]) 

(or some index array that will allow me to foo[indices] to sort foo... I'm not entirely sure what the best format for this is)
i.e.
pair_argsort([[1,2],[2,4]]) == [0,1]
pair_argsort([[2,1],[1,2]]) == [1,0]
pair_argsort([[1,2],[1,1]]) == [1,0] #NB

More generally (up to array/tuple/listification):
pair_of_pairs[pair_argsort(pair_of_pairs)]) == sorted(map(tuple, pair_of_pairs))

I could then np.apply_along_axis(pair_argsort,...) to argsort the entirety of foo.  It would be nice, though, if there were some numpy-native way to do this rather than applying my python function, which seems inefficient.
I can argsort by just the first value in the tuple with np.argsort(foo.reshape(-1, 2, 2), axis=1)[:,:,0]:
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]]) 

Note that this is wrong on the third pair of pairs [[3,2],[3,1]].
(I'm still not super sure how to use this to index foo to get the sorted array... will update when I figure that out.  :)
How can I "tuple argsort" in numpy?

Could you provide the output you would want for foo?

I couldn't find any other way for numpy to "ignore" the deepest dimension than to convert the innermost pairs to tuples (like you seem you have tried).
Thus, based on the accepted answer for this post (Convert last dimension of ndarray to tuple/recarray), this yields your desired output:
def full_argsort(my_array):
    new_array = my_array.view(dtype=np.dtype([('x', my_array.dtype), ('y', my_array.dtype)]))
    new_array = new_array.reshape(new_array.shape[:-1])
    return new_array.argsort()

Output of full_argsort(foo):
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]], dtype=int64)


Or in one line, using a newish recfunctions function: np.argsort(np.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured(foo,'i,i'))

Nice one; you might want to add your own answer.
